# Postgres window functions - rank() partition by bigint

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm trying to rank data over partition by a column thats type is bigint but it isn't working when I change the column in the partition by to a column of type timestamp with time zone it does work.

My query looks like this:

```
select id,ts_insert,serial_no,rank() over (partition by serial_no order by serial_no desc) from schema.table_name
```

The result looks like this:

```
1,'2019-02-19 18:27:50.258846+11',19516,1
1,'2019-02-19 18:27:50.258846+11',19515,1
1,'2019-02-19 18:27:50.258846+11',19514,1
1,'2019-02-06 19:45:38.896062+11',15069,1
1,'2019-02-05 21:46:28.633325+11',14827,1
```

Expected result is:

```
1,'2019-02-19 18:27:50.258846+11',19516,1
1,'2019-02-19 18:27:50.258846+11',19515,2
1,'2019-02-19 18:27:50.258846+11',19514,3
1,'2019-02-06 19:45:38.896062+11',15069,4
1,'2019-02-05 21:46:28.633325+11',14827,5
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select id, ts_insert, serial_no,
       rank() over (partition by id order by serial_no desc)
from schema.table_name;
```

`serial_no` is unique (at least in the data you've provided).  If you partition by a unique column, then the `rank()` will always be `1`.

Comment: That's correct serial_no is unique, thanks for your response. What can I use to select the highest value in the serial_no column?

Comment: @Victor . . . That is what the `order by` does.  If you want to *filter* the results, use a subquery and add `where rnk = 1`.